# RegEx to match only numbers incorrectly matching

Tags: javascript, regex, numbers, match

I'm trying to use a regular expression in JavaScript to match a number or a number containing a decimal. The regular expression looks like `[0-9]+ | [0-9]* \. [0-9]+`.

However, for some reason this `'1A'.match(/^[0-9]+|[0-9]*\.[0-9]+$/)` incorrectly finds a match. I'm not sure which part of the expression is matching the `A`.

Comment: `'1A'.match(/^([0-9]+|[0-9]*\.[0-9]+)$/)` group it

Comment: Looks like something that could be handled by ´parseFloat´ Without any need for a RegExp

Comment: Why do you need that? Is that for validating input or what?

Comment: I'm writing a tokenizer for CSS3 based on http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-syntax/#tokenization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your alternation. This is what it says:

```
  ^[0-9]+           # match an integer at the start
|                   # OR
  [0-9]*\.[0-9]+$   # match a decimal number at the end
```

So the first alternative matches.

You need to group the alternation:

```
/^(?:[0-9]+|[0-9]*\.[0-9]+)$/
```

The `?:` is an optimisation and a good habit. It suppresses capturing which is not needed in the given case.

You could get away without the alternation as well, though:

```
/^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$/
```

Or even shorter:

```
/^\d*\.?\d+$/
```

Comment: +1 for good explanation, you typed so much in such a short time :)

Comment: I didn't know about `?:`. +1

Comment: What is the OP expecting to get with a string of "1.24a"?

Comment: @Xotic750 a mismatch, I suppose

Comment: You can simply do `/^\d+$/` to match only digits (which is not null)

Comment: @ashish2expert did you read the question? "I'm trying to use a regular expression in JavaScript to match a number or a number containing a decimal. "

Answer (score 3):

`'1A'.match(/^[0-9]+|[0-9]*\.[0-9]+$/)` finds a match because it is a union of:

`^[0-9]+`

and

`[0-9]*\.[0-9]+$`

where the first matches.

to avoid this, group them: `^([0-9]+|[0-9]*\.[0-9]+)$`

and try this:

`'1A'.match(/^([0-9]+|[0-9]*\.[0-9]+)$/) === null`

---

### alternatively:

```
function matchExacly(str, regex) {
    var tmp = str.match(regex);
    return tmp ? tmp[0] === str : false;
}

matchExacly('1A', /[0-9]+|[0-9]*\.[0-9]+/) === false

matchExacly('1', /[0-9]+|[0-9]*\.[0-9]+/) === true
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am at the wrong place but if you use regex just for validating numeric values, why not to use faster alternatives, as the following:

```
var isNumber = ( +n === parseFloat(n) );
```

Comment: that will never return true, as it's comparing a number and a string, will it? maybe if you make that two `==`. But `parseFloat` accepts scientific `e` notation, doesn't it? and that was not part of the specification. anyway, generally good thought

Comment: @m.buettner Yeah, if `n` is string type then `+n` should fix the problem.